# Console.ReadLine ignored in .Net Core app on Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, raspberry-pi, .net-core, windows-10-iot-core

As an early foray into IoT development I've written a simple "Hello World" console app in .Net Core 2.0 / C# and deployed it to a Raspberry Pi running Windows 10 IoT.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World");
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine("Terminating");
}
```

Using [this awesome article](https://jeremylindsayni.wordpress.com/2017/07/03/automating-net-core-2-deployments-to-different-platforms-with-cake/) by Jeremy Lindsay I've published the EXE to my PI and then remotely executed it in a PowerShell window. The app runs fine, asides from one rather odd issue - rather than waiting for me to hit Enter after outputting "Hello World", it seems to skip the call to Console.ReadLine() and immediately displays the text "Terminating" before closing out cleanly.

I can find no reason for this odd behaviour - does anyone have an explanation and is there any way to get this to behave properly?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue looks like related to PowerShell. 
You can use [SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot-core/connect-your-device/ssh) as a workaround.

Comment: The app does indeed work as expected when executed through SSH. I wonder why it ignores the ReadLine() in powershell...  Thanks very much for your help!